# How to get last inserted id from insert method laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have inserted value in database from the `Model`, here is the code:

**Controller:**

```
class MovieController extends Controller
{   
    /**
     * Create a new movie model instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(MovieModel $movie){
        $this->movie = $movie;
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(MovieRequest $request)
    {               
        if($this->movie->createMovie($input)){
            return Redirect::back()->with('message', '<strong>' . $input['name'] . '</strong> movie has been created');
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
class Movie extends Model
{   
    public function createMovie($input) {
        return $this->insert($input);   // I need to return last inserted id here
    }

}
```

**By using this insert method how can I get the last inserted id?**

Comment: Show your insert function code..

Comment: I am calling the insert function of laravel Illuminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, add this code:

```
public function createMovie($input) {
    $id = $this->insertGetId(
        $input
    );

    return $id;
}
```

See, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your table has `autoincrementid` field then Try using `insertGetId` function which will return last inserted row id

```
return DB::table('movie')->insertGetId(
    //pass an array parameter to this function
);
```

[Laravel Query Builder Reference](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#inserts)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Movie extends Model
{   
    public function createMovie($input) {
        $insertedId = $this->insert($input);   // I need to     return last inserted id here
       $theId = (int) $inserted->id;

        return $theId;
    }

}
```

This suppose that '$this->insert($input);' is the query you are executing.

To give you the idea you get the id directly fron your executed query:

```
$qry = $this->movie->createMovie($input)
$insertedId = $qry->id
```